# Array when passed as index to an array, doesn't give expected result

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I tried passing an array as index to different array and count the occurrence of index pair.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,2],[0,1],[1,2]])
b = np.zeros((3,3))
for i in range(0,a.shape[1]):

  b[a[:,i],i] = b[a[:,i],i] + 1

print(b)
```

[And this the output i got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/py5ML.png)

I was expecting the output to be
b = [[1,0,0],[2,1,0],[0,2,0]]

Can anyone explain where I have gone wrong? Please suggest if you know a way to do this without using for loop

Comment: Please, provide the output from the screenshot in the text form in your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your code is that you are using the same index variable `i` to iterate through both dimensions of the array `a`. You should be iterating through the rows of `a` in the outer loop and the columns of `a` in the inner loop to correctly count the occurrence of index pairs.

Here is code with loop:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1,2],[0,1],[1,2]])
b = np.zeros((3,3))

for i in range(a.shape[0]):
    for j in range(a.shape[1]):
        b[a[i,j],j] += 1

print(b)
```

and if you want to do it without a loops you can use [bincount](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html)  function with advanced indexing

Here is how your code will look like:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1,2],[0,1],[1,2]])
b = np.zeros((3,3))

for i in range(a.shape[1]):
    b[:,i] = np.bincount(a[:,i], minlength=b.shape[0])

print(b)
```